# call div from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am having one div for dialog box in the html and I want that dialog box should open when the function in the controller is called.

This is my div which the function should open.

```
<div id="example" role="dialog" class="modal fade" 
style="top: 80px;left: 370px;right: 20px;width: 500px;
height: 600px;margin: 0;overflow: auto;">

<h6>some text</h6>
</div>
```

This is my function in the controller.

```
NumberService.getNumberList(result.auth_token).then(function(result){
                if(result.status == "success"){
                    $scope.data = result.data;
                    var Home= document.getElementById("example");
                    Home.style.display="";
                }else{
                    $scope.status = result.status;
                }
            });
```

I have used document.getElementByID but its not working. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You should not do DOM manipulation inside your controller. Your problem calls for using directives. You should define a custom directive to define your div and it's behavior.

Comment: you may use ng-show or ng-hide and set the value of varible in that your function it may works for you

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id=example ng-show="data.show">

$scope.data = result.data;
$scope.data.show = true;
```

You can update `data.show` as a boolean to determine whether the element will be shown or not in the given scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your html have:

```
<div ng-show="status == 'success'" id="example" ...>
    <h6>some text</h6>
</div>
```

And then in your controllers function you can manipulate the $scope.status variable:

```
NumberService.getNumberList(result.auth_token).then(function(result){
    if (result.status == "success"){
        $scope.data = result.data;
        $scope.status = "success";
    } 
    else {
         $scope.status = result.status;
    }
});
```